# Convert strange return codes from Winforms KeyEventArgs.KeyData, such as 'Oemtilde' and 'Oem6'?

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization, keyboard, keyevent

I want to display the result of a key press or combination to the user.  The purpose is because I want the user to visually see what key combination they've used for a keyboard shortcut they've defined themselves as part of a greater program. To clarify further, the user clicks in a read-only TextBox, and it will automatically display in that box the key combination they've pressed.

Unfortunately, on my UK keyboard, when I press the quote key for example, .NET Winforms returns 'Oemtilde' from the KeyData property in the `KeyEventArgs` event. Perhaps for a US or other foreign keyboard, that WOULD actually be the tilde key, but to a UK user, of course it would look strange.

Other keys suffer from odd looking return codes too ('Oem6' or 'Next' for example). How can I convert these strange codes to what a user expects to see them as?

Comment: asp.net? wpf? winforms? KeyEventArgs is different between these options

Comment: This is an XY question.  Mapping virtual keys to typing keys is an operating system job, it greatly depends on the active keyboard layout and the process-local keyboard state.  Always use the KeyPress event, **never** try to do this yourself.  If this is XY because you are hiding a key logger project then fuggedaboutid, you can't write one in C#.

Comment: @HansPassant: The purpose is because I want the user to see what key combination they've used for a keyboard shortcut they've defined themselves. Nothing less innocent than that. Unfortunately, the KeyPress event won't handle special keys like PageDown, and I'd need a way to convert it back to the `Keys` type anyway (as my GlobalHotkeys class uses that information).

Comment: I'll never understand why we have to guess at these things.  We'll have you guess how the ToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys is capable of generating a displayable string.

Comment: @HansPassant: Sorry, not sure I follow. To clarify, the user will be choosing a *custom* hotkey. They click in a TextBox, press the key combo they want, and the textbox will display what combo they've pressed. It's the most intuitive and versatile way I've seen for choosing a shortcut/hotkey, though I've only seen one program use it before.

Comment: @HansPassant: Oh you probably meant why I made it 'XY' to begin with. Well, in honesty, I thought the question was pretty well self-contained even as it was, and even though I've now explained my purpose more thoroughly, I doubt that would have much if any impact on potential answers. By adding more info, it also makes the question appear less general to other users who may be having the same problem but in a different context.